# c# reports

Tags: c#, .net

Hi anybody please tell me how to use reports in c# , specifically rdlc please explain its architecture and if possible please post some sample code.

Comment: do you mean crystal reports? or other kind of report?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good illustrated article on the subject:

[Beginner's guide for creating standalone .rdlc reports with ssrs](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/robo60/StandaloneRDLCReports11142007183516PM/StandaloneRDLCReports.aspx)